# How to create sub set of data in equal random distribution considering multiple condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the below-mentioned df in R:

```
x <- structure(list(ID = c("I-1", "I-2", "I-3", "I-4", "I-5", "I-6", 
"I-7", "I-8", "I-9", "I-10", "I-11"), Unique_Id = c("UR-112", 
"UR-112", "UR-112", "UR-113", "UR-113", "UR-114", "UR-114", "UR-114", 
"UR-115", "UR-115", "UR-116"), Date = c("2020-01-01 14:15:16", 
"2020-02-12 14:15:16", "2020-03-23 14:15:16", "2020-01-01 14:15:16", 
"2020-04-11 14:15:16", "2020-04-07 14:15:16", "2020-05-08 14:15:16", 
"2020-05-09 14:15:16", "2020-01-18 14:15:16", "2020-03-23 14:15:16", 
"2020-02-11 14:15:16"), Status = c("Approved", "In Process", 
"In Process", "Hold", "Hold", "Approved", "Approved", "In Process", 
"Approved", "Approved", "Approved")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I need to create a sub set of random 3 Unique_Id which is spread across all `Date` and these three Unique_Id must come under the available Status.

Required Output:

```
ID      Unique_Id      Date                  Status
I-1     UR-112         2020-01-01 14:15:16   Approved
I-2     UR-112         2020-02-12 14:15:16   In Process
I-3     UR-112         2020-03-23 14:15:16   In Process
I-4     UR-113         2020-01-01 14:15:16   Hold
I-5     UR-113         2020-04-11 14:15:16   Hold
I-11    UR-116         2020-02-11 14:15:16   Approved
```

I am trying the following code but it takes so much time to generate on 1000 thousand dataset, and I need to perform this logic on a dataset which has more than 1 Million rows.

code:

```
id <- character(0)
while(length(id) != 3) {
  id <- character(0)
  for(i in unique(x$Status)) {id <-
   c(id, sample(setdiff(x$Unique_Id[x$Status == i], id), 1))}
}

x[x$Unique_Id %in% id,]
```

Comment: Please help me understand "must come under the available status". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @PavoDive - It means that the subset should have some or equal proportion of `Unique_Id` with all the available unique status value in super set dataframe which is x.

Comment: your expected result doesn't match your description, then: you don't have a single case of UR-114 or UR-115.

Comment: @PavoDive- Yes, because I need to fetch only 3 `Unique_Id` rows.

Comment: You have nine unique values of `Date` in your dataset.  How can you sample three `Unique_Id`s "across all `Date`s?  As I commented on your previous question half an hour ago, if you need three `Unique_Id`s and have three possible `Status` codes, isn't your question asking to select one `Unique_ID` from each `Status` and then retain all records accoiated with those three `Unique_Id`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description is somewhat confusing, so this **may not be what you need**:

```
library(data.table) #This is fast, specially if your data is big

setDT(x) # converts x to data.table. Don't worry, it remains a data.frame too!

x[Unique_Id %in% sample(unique(Unique_Id), 3), ]
```

- `sample(unique(Unique_Id), 3)` takes the unique values of `Unique_Id` and randomly samples 3.
- `x[var %in% foo, ]` is data.table-se for "filter my table x when variable var is contained in vector foo".

### EDIT TO ADD:

After further clarification by the OP, the solution is more complex and looks like this:

First we need to find which `Unique_Id`s have an approximate distribution of 50% "Approved". Then we will sample 3 out of those `Unique_Id`s and retrieve all the information associated to them.

#### Step by step solution

```
IDs_OK <- x[, .N, 
              by = .(Unique_Id, Status == "Approved")][, 
        dcast(.SD, 
              Unique_Id ~ Status, 
              fill = 0)][
        (`TRUE` / (`TRUE` + `FALSE`)) %between% c(.4, .6), 
        sample(unique(Unique_Id), 3)]
```

- `x[, .N,by = .(Unique_Id, Status == "Approved")]` Counts cases (.N) by each combination of Unique_Id and status (it will return TRUE where approved, and FALSE otherwise)
- We chain that result (that's the `][`) and convert the table to wide (`dcast` with Unique_Id in the rows and TRUE and FALSE in the columns. `fill = 0` instructs to fill with 0 when no case is found.
- We chain that result and filter the cases where the proportion of "TRUEs" is between 40 - 60%.
- For those cases, we take the unique Unique_Ids and sample 3 out of them.
- We assing those 3 Unique_Ids to a variable called `IDs_OK`.

  x[Unique_Id %in% IDs_OK, ] # this is your expected result.

#### One-line solution:

It is possible to use a join in the data.table style (`X[Y, on = "var"]` joins X to Y on variable `var`):

```
x[x[, .N, by = .(Unique_Id, Status == "Approved")][, dcast(.SD, Unique_Id ~ Status, fill = 0)][(`TRUE` / (`TRUE` + `FALSE`)) %between% c(.4, .6), .(Unique_Id = sample(unique(Unique_Id), 3))], on = "Unique_Id"]
```

The only difference is in the last line, where I used `.(Unique_Id = sample(unique(Unique_Id), 3))`. The dot returns the result as a data.table, a condition necessary to make the join.

Comment: This solution works fast but not gives an equal distribution of `Status`. Is there a way to have sub set in a way that 50% `Unique_ID` fetched where `Status` is 'Approved` and rest 50% consist all.

Comment: 50% of 3 `Unique_ID` would be 1.5. Do you want 2 or do you want 1?

Comment: It was just an example :) It will work if I'll fetch 25000 records.

Comment: Also, in the case of 1.5 I want 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked perfect. Please let me know how can I add multiple % condition on different different status. For Example, 50% Approved and 30% Hold.

Comment: That requires rewriting it all... but an easy workaround will be to go with the step by step solution, remove the "sample" of the last line (so you get all Unique_Ids with approved around 50% and store those IDs in a variable. Then repeat the same steps, but grouping by HOLD and change the range from, say 25-35%. Then `intersect` both vectors and sample 3 out of the resulting insersected vector.